# How to echo json data values without double quote

Tags: php, json

I am created a web service and it returns json data as follows.
[{"lat":"6.8658","lng":"79.8744"}]

But I actually need like following.
[{"lat":6.8658,"lng":79.8744}]

My php code is as follows

```
$location_data= $this->db->query("SELECT lat,lng FROM jobs WHERE job_code='JO34656'")->result_array();

echo json_encode($location_data);
```

Comment: what is the difference between them?? Just `string` and `number`?? You can change it while reading `json decode` or before encode make the value as decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast all elements into `floatval`:

```
$location_data = $this->db->query("SELECT lat,lng FROM jobs WHERE job_code='JO34656'")->result_array();
$data = json_encode(array_map(function($e){
    return array_map('floatval', $e);
}, $location_data));
```

Or just pick whichever column you want casted:

```
$location_data = json_encode(array_map(function($e){
    foreach($e as $key => &$loc) {
        if(in_array($key, array('lat', 'lng'))) {
            $loc = floatval($loc);
        }
    }
    return $e;
}, $location_data));
```

Comment: add anything else to select statement and it goes wrong.

Comment: @MateuszSip what do you mean _add anything else to select_? you mean add another column on `SELECT lat, lng, date`? this answer covers the current question and should suffice (unless the OP suddenly changes it)

Comment: Exactly. We should give OP a good solution, not "something that works in this particular case". 
And extending that query to include different types data is natural, so it won't be helpful.

Comment: This is the answer I exactly looked for. Thank you #Rodrigo

Comment: @user2971013 sure glad this helped

Answer (score 4):

Use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, That encodes `numeric strings` as `numbers`.

> This option was added from 5.3.3.

```
$location_data= $this->db->query("SELECT lat,lng FROM jobs WHERE job_code='JO34656'")->result_array();

echo json_encode($location_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // [{"lat":6.8658,"lng":79.8744}]
```

More about: [JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: at least such option exists

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str.replace("Original", "Replacement");` syntax perhaps?

```
var test = "\"TEST\"";
test.replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

`"TEST"` -> `TEST`

Answer (score -2):

You can create a view model which converts values on creation.

Comment: I assumed that a view model concept is something googleable and easy to understand, but you're right.

For OP:
You can create a simple PHP class representing your data and do typecasting in constructor.

That's good, because you'll get type hinting and easier extension/refactoring.
In my opinion, @Rodrigo Duterte's answer is a workaround, not a real solution.